# Passing a changed varriable that creates a split in the string from incomming parameter-Python

Tags: python, return

I have created a working version of the assignment. I am not asking for anyone to do my assignment as it already creates the correct output.

However, there is most certainly a better way. I am just wondering what that is. The code is broken into two files (driver and runner) and is ran through a .bat. 
First part is unchangeable.

```
import Proj07Runner

str = 'The lazy brown fox'
index = 6
myList = Proj07Runner.run(str,index)
print(str)
for item in str:
    print(item)
```

And the second:

```
import sys
import os
def run(str,index):

    print (str)
    print (index)
    print (str)
    mylist = (str)
    mylist = mylist[:6]
    print (mylist)
    mylist = (str)
    mylist = mylist[6:]
    print(mylist)
    sys.exit()

    print (mylist)
    return(str,index)
```

The required output is

```
The lazy brown fox
6
The lazy brown fox
The la
azy brown fox
```

Overall, how am I able to return the string on two lines following the instructors code instead of instantiating it in my portion?

Comment: Why is there a batch file? What's that doing?

Comment: It is how the instructor is running the programs.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. Is your code producing the expected output? Are you asking how to improve it in some way? (If so, what would you like to improve?)

Comment: The code is working, and I believe there to be a more efficient way of doing this task.  other than forcing the system to stop after my portion of the code. Overall more cohesive with his.

Comment: This sentence in particular is giving me trouble: "Initially used sys.stdout to stop the driver class from running any more code. Changed it to an OS operation due to it being ran from a .Bat file, and when ran outside of IDLE with sys. it allowed the driver to continue." I have no idea what any of this means.

Comment: disregard that part. I'll fix it... originally I used sys.std to prevent his code and stop it at the end of mine had to change it to sys.exit(). The initial portion caused his lines to run.

Comment: I know you said you can't change it, but that first part can't possibly be right... it ignores the return value of your function and then just prints the input one character at a time. `myList` is created and then completely disregarded.

Comment: Thank-you; this was copy and pasted directly from the assignment and could not figure out how to not stop his script and have it work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you're supposed to return a string that prints on two lines, split at the indicated index position.  If so, then simply do that much: return a string composed of

- The first 6 characters (taking the index of 6 from your example)
- a newline character
- The rest of the string

In short:

```
def run(str,index):
    return str[:index] + '\n' + str[index:]
```

Is that what you needed?

Comment: Yes, however; your code is printing one copy of str and the for loop is causing it to break down to one char on every line (which is similar to why I stopped his script from running after mine). The required output is :
        str
        index
        str
        the la
        zy brown fox

Comment: The driver script inherently prints one character of `str` on every line.  Since `str` is immutable, and you're not allowed to change the driver code, you have no way to stop that as far as I can see.  I'm somewhat confused about the driver's purpose, since it utterly ignores the return value from your `run` function.

Comment: Thank-you! It is copy and pasted directly from his code, and for the life of me could not figure out what I needed to do other than stopping his portion to get the correct answer. Sorry for the inconvenience, just could not conceive how to do it with his code running with mine. So now I know it is not just me.

Comment: If that's truly the instructor's exact code, you should notify your instructor that it's broken. (Presumably everyone in the class will have the same problem.)